# Land borders between Thailand and Cambodia that accept Cambodian e-Visa

Tags: visas, borders, thailand, cambodia, e-visas

I am planning to travel next winter (October 2018 to January 2019) to Thailand, Cambodia and Vietnam. What I want to do is to cross the land border between Thailand and Cambodia by train or coach (ideally walking, I mean I'm not flying anyway).

I have read on https://www.evisa.gov.kh/FAQ that

> Not all border checkpoints support e-Visa.

But I can't find any list of checkpoint places that accept that document instead. My idea at the moment is to request the e-Visa anyway: in the *worst case* I'll pay the affordable price twice and show my best effort...

Does anybody know one or more checkpoints that would accept e-Visas?
Any reference or direct experience shared would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no train, yet, between Thailand and Cambodia. That leaves you with a bus. If you're going from Bangkok, that means you'll cross at Poipet. Where the eVisa is accepted. If you're wandering around, there are a couple of other options.

Now, as for the list of places where it is accepted, it will appear when filling out the form: the form asks you where you plan to cross, and there's a popup menu.

[image]

EDIT:

Timatic (checked via Emirates) says:

[image]

Which is complete bull. I've done day trips to Poipet, on a single-entry eVisa, where I spent more time on the road than inside Cambodia.

Comment: _as for the list of places where it is accepted, it will appear when filling out the form_: I just had a deeper check on the website (evisa.gov.kh), and it's exactly as you wrote and showed. Top!

Comment: That's because I went in and started an application online :-)

Comment: I passed the border yesterday and can confirm they accept eVisa in Poipet! :)